# ScheduledTask using NotebookEvaluate on a Cloud notebook

Tags: scheduledtask

I would like to **CloudSubmit** a **ScheduledTask** using the function 
**NotebookEvaluate** to run a notebook stored in the Cloud.

I am concluding NotebookEvaluate will not evaluate a notebook that is stored in the Cloud, as follows:

`CloudSubmit[ScheduledTask[NotebookEvaluate["MyCloudNotebook.nb",InsertResults->True], "Daily"]`